# How to use the PublishingPageImage with image rendition in a page layout?

Tags: page-layout, image-rendition

I setup image rendition on my farm. I add my custom image rendition item with a specific width and height. Now I would like to add the PublishingPageImage to a page layout and make it using the image rendition.

I found this [tutorial](http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/optimize-content-authoring-experience-image-renditions-and-device-channels-part-2)

And I add these controls to my page layout to test it:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" RenditionId="6"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" RenditionId="5"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" RenditionId="4"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageImage" RenditionId="3"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
```

But I still see the same size of the picture. What I am doing wrong?

Like you see below I edit the news article page, add a picture and leave the image rendition. I save the page, check in and publish. I stil see the 4 pictures in my news article without image rendition. Do I need to do some crawl or something?

[image]

See below the device channels, there is only the default device channel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the page through a difference device (ie an iPad or Windows Phone) or through a browser's developer console that is emulating a different device? You can also change the rules for the device channel through Site Settings > Device Channels.

Comment: I am just on my dev environment. Win Server 2013, IE 10, compatibility mode turned off.

Comment: What are the other device channels that you're trying to view it as?

Comment: see update for the printscreen of the device channels. There is only the default device channel.

Comment: 1) Since you're seeing all four at once and the tutorial you linked to was specifically about image renditions for device channels instead of in general, do you have these inside of a device channel panel? 2) You should name them differently in FieldName (PublishingPageImage, PublishingPageImage_big, The Primary Publishing Page Image, etc)

Comment: no I do not using device channels. I just add the image rendition parameter to my image control. So I just need to add one control each. 2 or more of the same controls is not possible.

Comment: Alright, then that tutorial may not be the best one to use. Without the device channel panel, it will display all four of those images as is. The panel makes the decision on which image to display. Try [this](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/image-renditions-sharepoint-2013/) tutorial. It breaks down to 1) Turn on BLOB cache in web config 2) use Settings > Image Renditions 3) Go to Site Contents > Image library/Site Collection Images > Edit Renditions